# How would i catch a GET 404 (Not Found) Error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, get

```
videoplayer.src = "vids/video" + count.toString() + ".mp4"
```

My code makes a request for the specified file and it returns

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/vids/video3.mp4 404 (Not Found)
```

As it should because that file does not exist, but how do i catch this? I want to do something when it is caught.

I have tried with a try/catch but it didn't seem to catch it at all
I have also tried with

```
window.onerror = function(error) {
    document.location.reload(true)
  };
```

Which also did not catch the bad request

Comment: `videoplayer.onerror` instead of `window.onerror`? I'm not sure if you can actually catch the response status code.

Comment: Are you on the same domain as the non-working video or is cross domain? In case its on the same, you could simply try to send a get request.

Comment: @Ivar That actually worked! It seems to catch the "Error" and reloads the page :) if you put it in answers i'll mark tt as the solution :)

Comment: @Aaron This code is all local and the video in question is in the parent directory of the script

Comment: The above question also has the answer. No need to repeat it. :-)